# Regex match url of image

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to match image url that start from "//" and end with ".jpg" or ".png" or "gif".
so I made following regular expressions and it works but not all cases..

```
var pattern = /\/{2}.+?\.(jpg|png|gif)/gm;
```

The problem is,
It also matches something that looks like this,

**//**pm.pstatic.net/dist/css/nmain.20201119.css">     <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="https://s.pstatic.net/static/www/u/2014/0328/mma_204243574**.png**

And this is not what I want obiously.
I need to match last occurence of "//" and lazy match of ".png" or ".jpg" or "gif".
In this case, It will be **//s.pstatic.net/static/www/u/2014/0328/mma_204243574.png**

What should I use to solve this problem?

**+edit**

The website that I want to scrape contains image url something looks like this.

**<a href="javascript:;" style="background:url(//gd4.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/2748816012/O1CN01gbXzeB1uHXhQ9eTVd_!!2748816012.jpg_30x30.jpg)**

so normal image url matcher doesn't work.

also, It must be lazy match of ".jpg" because as you can see above url,
it has image address like **//gd4.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/2748816012/O1CN01gbXzeB1uHXhQ9eTVd_!!2748816012.jpg_30x30.jpg**

it needs to be end at first occurrence of ".jpg", otherwise I will only scrape 30x30 small image which I don't want. In this case, img url that I want is, **//gd4.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/2748816012/O1CN01gbXzeB1uHXhQ9eTVd_!!2748816012.jpg**

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Thanks for the commeting. I just tried that but It's not working. It matches from "//" to "."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
/\/\/(\S+?(?:jpe?g|png|gif))/ig
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ry39k/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\/\/`: Match `//`
- `(`: Start capture group #1
- `\S+?`: Match 1+ non-whitespaces (lazy)
- `(?:jpe?g|png|gif)`: Match `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` or `gif`
- `)`: End capture group

Comment: not working properly

Comment: May be your problem is different

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following regex:

```
(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)
```

Also, you can test your Regex here:

https://regex101.com/r/l2Zt7S/1

Just for fun, here's a Regex that matches all types of image urls:

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)+$
```

What intrigues me is how to select the last occurrence of "//". But let's see if someone comes up with a way to solve that.

Here's the match that I got when I tested my Regex with the URL you shared.

[image: Match Description Image]

Comment: Thanks aryashah2k! But the website I want to scrape has image address something like this "background:url(//gd4.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/2748816012/O1CN01gbXzeB1uHXhQ9eTVd_!!2748816012.jpg_30x30.jpg)" It doesn't have "http:" in the begging. I tried your code and it works perfectly if image url has "http:" but when I erased the "http:" part it's not working.